# Perl: How to post specific data to a particular URL and save the response in a text file, in a web scraping context?

Tags: perl

I would like to post the below data to a particular URL:

```
choice  yes
high    high
low     low
name    BDNL
```

To this URL:

```
https://www.example.com
```

I would then like to save the response whether HTML or plain text in a text file?

I have experience with Perl and would prefer to use it for the purpose of this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use CGI;

my $url = 'http://www.example.com/';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $ua->post( $url, { choice => "yes", high => "high", low => "low", name => "BDNL" } );
my $content = $response->decoded_content();

my $cgi = CGI->new();
open my $fh, ">", "response.txt" or die "$!";
print $fh $cgi->header() . $content;
close $fh;
```

Comment: You need `CGI`, as when I compiled (don't think PERL is interpretted) it said `Can't locate object method "new" via package "CGI" you forgot to load perhaps`

Comment: Hi @Matt, all that is returned is `Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` in the textfile, The site I am using uses authentication so this may be an issue as I first use `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` to log in but then it seems incorrect to use LWP as this I assume uses a different (unauthenticated) instance?

Comment: @StevieG can you use [WWW::Mechnize::Firefox's post](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.74/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm#$mech-%3Epost%28_$url,_%options_%29)? Use `$mech->content();` to get the decoded content.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I tried that but now I am getting `Can't locate object method "post" via package "WWW::Mechanize::Firefox"`, I think it could be my version though I'm on 0.71 and can't update to 0.74. But I won't waste your time.

Comment: @StevieG yeah I bet it was added later. There may be a way to authenticate with LWP:UserAgent so maybe that is something to look into too (or if you could upgrade).